# How to open a Bootstrap modal from the right?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to make Bootstrap modal to take full window height and open it from right side as like sidebar? It mean it should be right aligned.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: it might be helpful :)
https://codepen.io/bootpen/pen/jbbaRa

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a way (inspired from this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yqpvu6sd/)) by adding a CSS class `right` to the modal to display it from the right side.

```css
.modal.fade:not(.in).right .modal-dialog {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(25%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(25%, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade right">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;<span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open modal from the right</a>
```

Comment: I want to set it to be right aligned, like we have sidebars?
I have asked that!

Answer (score 10):

Add this CSS class "come-from-modal right" in right side with "modal fade"

```css
.come-from-modal.left .modal-dialog,
.come-from-modal.right .modal-dialog {
    position: fixed;
    margin: auto;
    width: 320px;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
}

.come-from-modal.left .modal-content,
.come-from-modal.right .modal-content {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    border-radius: 0px;
}

.come-from-modal.left .modal-body,
.come-from-modal.right .modal-body {
    padding: 15px 15px 80px;
}
.come-from-modal.right.fade .modal-dialog {
    right: -320px;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
}

.come-from-modal.right.fade.in .modal-dialog {
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Launch demo modal
</button>

<div class="modal fade  come-from-modal right" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! A full height modal coming from the right side that stays attached to the side of the screen. Thank you sir!

Comment: in Bootstrap 5.3 version you have to replace the ".in" class with the ".show" class, the last part of the code would be:

.come-from-modal.right.fade.show .modal-dialog {
    right: 0;
}

Answer (score 0):

```css
.modal.fade:not(.in).right .modal-dialog {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(25%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(25%, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade right">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;<span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open modal from the right</a>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).